# construct javascript object containing dictionary of items

Tags: javascript, json

I (re)wrote a script that generates a javascript object containing a dictionary of items.

It generates the output in the following format

```
{"Item":158567,"Crumb":23525076,"Utilities":62648}
```

However, my initial script (which I seem to have lost), generated output in this format, which is more useful for me.

```
{"sizes":{"Item":158567,"Crumb":23525076,"Utilities":62648}}
```

How can I modify the following script so as to be able to get this output? the only difference is, I expect the word "sizes" to show up

```
var fs = require('fs');

var path = '../apps/test-app/dist';
var sizes = {};
var outputFilePath = '../apps/test-app/dist/sizes.json';

fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var file = path + '/' + items[i];

    const isJavascriptFile = items[i].match(/.js$/);
    if (isJavascriptFile) {
      var fileName = getComponentName(items[i]);
      var fileSize = getFilesizeInBytes(file);
      sizes[fileName] = fileSize;
    }
  }

  fs.writeFileSync(outputFilePath, JSON.stringify(sizes));
});

function getFilesizeInBytes(fileName) {
  const stats = fs.statSync(fileName);
  const fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;
  return fileSizeInBytes;
}

function getComponentName(fileName) {
  return fileName.match('ui-(.*).min.js')[1];
}
```

Comment: Change `JSON.stringify(sizes)` to `JSON.stringify({sizes: sizes})`

Comment: Try changing `fs.writeFileSync(outputFilePath, JSON.stringify(sizes));` to `fs.writeFileSync(outputFilePath, JSON.stringify({ sizes }));`? Note the `{}` around sizes

Comment: hey @TylerRoper it's the new ES6 syntax. `{ sizes }` is equivalent to `{ sizes: sizes }`

Comment: @AravindanVe +1 You're absolutely right. (Relevant docs: [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment))

Comment: @AravindanVe , Tyler Roper, both great answers, and work for me. Thanks for helping out. If either would like to add as an answer, please go ahead.

Comment: Haha no need, you can just mark the question as resolved :)

Comment: @AravindanVe unless I'm missing something, I cannot mark a comment as resolved, it needs to be an answer?

Comment: Oh okay. I did not know that :D

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
fs.writeFileSync(outputFilePath, JSON.stringify(sizes));
```

**to**

```
fs.writeFileSync(outputFilePath, JSON.stringify({ sizes }));
```

Note the **{ }** around `sizes`